# Using Like in Rails SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I got a little problem using the LIKE sentence on rails i know that this next sentence works:

```
Brand.find(:all, :joins=>[:cars], :conditions=>["brandname LIKE ?","%ford%"])
```

But it's any way around that I could to something like this:

```
Brand.find(:all, :joins=>[:cars], :conditions=>["brandname LIKE '%ford%'"])
```

Its because i already have a function that returns all conditions on a single string, but i require to support search in strings and i don't really how to get it work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain that I understand what you're talking about.  Are you trying to pass in a variable into the conditions?

I would re-write this query just a tad.

```
Brand.all.joins(:cars).where("brandname LIKE ?", "%#{some_variable}%")
```

Of course selecting all can be bad for performance if you get a lot of records so you may want to consider limiting that or paginating the results somehow.

I would recommend the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions).  Using an array would be great in this instance

```
Brand.all.joins(:cars).where("brandname LIKE ?", "%#{params[:brand_search]}%")
```

Comment: You definitely want to use the ? since it will offer you some protection from unsafe inputs.

Comment: you will need to change the solution slightly, need "%#{params[:brand_search]}%" instead of just params[:brand_search] if you want it to match partials

Comment: Good call Ben.  Fixed it in my response.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem is that i got a function that i just send some params that pass my form (My form its dynamic so the user can add or delete search fields). So my method depend on the amount of params that i send i got back a string like: ""price > 500 and year > 2002 and brand LIKE ?","#{some_variable}%"" and i insert that string over my conditions. But I didn't find a clear way to get that work. Any ideas? :)

Comment: You could possibly build your string out in a separate function.  Or just have the whole query built out and pass in default params.

Comment: So for example, brandname = params[:brand_search] || ""
Then pass in the brandname